# C++ eos - Error loading the Morphable Model: Error opening given file: ../share/sfm_shape_3448.bin

Tags: c++, open-source

I am trying to run [some software I found on github](https://github.com/patrikhuber/eos/blob/master/examples/fit-model-simple.cpp). I managed to compile and install everything on my ubuntu machine. However when trying to run one of the provided examples (fit-model-simple.cpp) I get the following error:

```
Error loading the Morphable Model: Error opening given file: ../share/sfm_shape_3448.bin
```

I tried to hard code the path to the file as well but the result stays the same.

Does anybody know what I might be doing wrong?

This is the code:

```
/*
 * eos - A 3D Morphable Model fitting library written in modern C++11/14.
 *
 * File: examples/fit-model-simple.cpp
 *
 * Copyright 2015 Patrik Huber
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
#include "eos/core/Landmark.hpp"
#include "eos/core/LandmarkMapper.hpp"
#include "eos/fitting/orthographic_camera_estimation_linear.hpp"
#include "eos/fitting/RenderingParameters.hpp"
#include "eos/fitting/linear_shape_fitting.hpp"
#include "eos/render/utils.hpp"
#include "eos/render/texture_extraction.hpp"

#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

#include "boost/program_options.hpp"
#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace eos;
namespace po = boost::program_options;
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
using eos::core::Landmark;
using eos::core::LandmarkCollection;
using cv::Mat;
using cv::Vec2f;
using cv::Vec3f;
using cv::Vec4f;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;
using std::string;

/**
 * Reads an ibug .pts landmark file and returns an ordered vector with
 * the 68 2D landmark coordinates.
 *
 * @param[in] filename Path to a .pts file.
 * @return An ordered vector with the 68 ibug landmarks.
 */
LandmarkCollection<cv::Vec2f> read_pts_landmarks(std::string filename)
{
    using std::getline;
    using cv::Vec2f;
    using std::string;
    LandmarkCollection<Vec2f> landmarks;
    landmarks.reserve(68);

    std::ifstream file(filename);
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        throw std::runtime_error(string("Could not open landmark file: " + filename));
    }

    string line;
    // Skip the first 3 lines, they're header lines:
    getline(file, line); // 'version: 1'
    getline(file, line); // 'n_points : 68'
    getline(file, line); // '{'

    int ibugId = 1;
    while (getline(file, line))
    {
        if (line == "}") { // end of the file
            break;
        }
        std::stringstream lineStream(line);

        Landmark<Vec2f> landmark;
        landmark.name = std::to_string(ibugId);
        if (!(lineStream >> landmark.coordinates[0] >> landmark.coordinates[1])) {
            throw std::runtime_error(string("Landmark format error while parsing the line: " + line));
        }
        // From the iBug website:
        // "Please note that the re-annotated data for this challenge are saved in the Matlab convention of 1 being
        // the first index, i.e. the coordinates of the top left pixel in an image are x=1, y=1."
        // ==> So we shift every point by 1:
        landmark.coordinates[0] -= 1.0f;
        landmark.coordinates[1] -= 1.0f;
        landmarks.emplace_back(landmark);
        ++ibugId;
    }
    return landmarks;
};

/**
 * This app demonstrates estimation of the camera and fitting of the shape
 * model of a 3D Morphable Model from an ibug LFPW image with its landmarks.
 *
 * First, the 68 ibug landmarks are loaded from the .pts file and converted
 * to vertex indices using the LandmarkMapper. Then, an orthographic camera
 * is estimated, and then, using this camera matrix, the shape is fitted
 * to the landmarks.
 */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
std::cerr<<"modif 1"<<endl;
    fs::path modelfile, isomapfile, imagefile, landmarksfile, mappingsfile, outputfile;
    try {
        po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
        desc.add_options()
            ("help,h",
                "display the help message")
            ("model,m", po::value<fs::path>(&modelfile)->required()->default_value("/home/yalishanda/Downloads/eos-master/share/sfm_shape_3448.bin"),
                "a Morphable Model stored as cereal BinaryArchive")
            ("image,i", po::value<fs::path>(&imagefile)->required()->default_value("/home/yalishanda/Downloads/eos-master/examples/data/image_0010.png"),
                "an input image")
            ("landmarks,l", po::value<fs::path>(&landmarksfile)->required()->default_value("/home/yalishanda/Downloads/eos-master/examples/data/image_0010.pts"),
                "2D landmarks for the image, in ibug .pts format")
            ("mapping,p", po::value<fs::path>(&mappingsfile)->required()->default_value("/home/yalishanda/Downloads/eos-master/share/ibug_to_sfm.txt"),
                "landmark identifier to model vertex number mapping")
            ("output,o", po::value<fs::path>(&outputfile)->required()->default_value("out"),
                "basename for the output rendering and obj files")
            ;
        po::variables_map vm;
        po::store(po::command_line_parser(argc, argv).options(desc).run(), vm);
        if (vm.count("help")) {
            cout << "Usage: fit-model-simple [options]" << endl;
            cout << desc;
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }
        po::notify(vm);
    }
    catch (const po::error& e) {
        cout << "Error while parsing command-line arguments: " << e.what() << endl;
        cout << "Use --help to display a list of options." << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Load the image, landmarks, LandmarkMapper and the Morphable Model:
    Mat image = cv::imread(imagefile.string());
    LandmarkCollection<cv::Vec2f> landmarks;
    try {
        landmarks = read_pts_landmarks(landmarksfile.string());
    }
    catch (const std::runtime_error& e) {
        cout << "Error reading the landmarks: " << e.what() << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    morphablemodel::MorphableModel morphable_model;
    try {
        morphable_model = morphablemodel::load_model(modelfile.string());
    }
    catch (const std::runtime_error& e) {
        cout << "Error loading the Morphable Model: " << e.what() << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    core::LandmarkMapper landmark_mapper = mappingsfile.empty() ? core::LandmarkMapper() : core::LandmarkMapper(mappingsfile);

    // Draw the loaded landmarks:
    Mat outimg = image.clone();
    for (auto&& lm : landmarks) {
        cv::rectangle(outimg, cv::Point2f(lm.coordinates[0] - 2.0f, lm.coordinates[1] - 2.0f), cv::Point2f(lm.coordinates[0] + 2.0f, lm.coordinates[1] + 2.0f), { 255, 0, 0 });
    }

    // These will be the final 2D and 3D points used for the fitting:
    vector<Vec4f> model_points; // the points in the 3D shape model
    vector<int> vertex_indices; // their vertex indices
    vector<Vec2f> image_points; // the corresponding 2D landmark points

    // Sub-select all the landmarks which we have a mapping for (i.e. that are defined in the 3DMM):
    for (int i = 0; i < landmarks.size(); ++i) {
        auto converted_name = landmark_mapper.convert(landmarks[i].name);
        if (!converted_name) { // no mapping defined for the current landmark
            continue;
        }
        int vertex_idx = std::stoi(converted_name.get());
        auto vertex = morphable_model.get_shape_model().get_mean_at_point(vertex_idx);
        model_points.emplace_back(Vec4f(vertex.x(), vertex.y(), vertex.z(), 1.0f));
        vertex_indices.emplace_back(vertex_idx);
        image_points.emplace_back(landmarks[i].coordinates);
    }

    // Estimate the camera (pose) from the 2D - 3D point correspondences
    fitting::ScaledOrthoProjectionParameters pose = fitting::estimate_orthographic_projection_linear(image_points, model_points, true, image.rows);
    fitting::RenderingParameters rendering_params(pose, image.cols, image.rows);

    // The 3D head pose can be recovered as follows:
    float yaw_angle = glm::degrees(glm::yaw(rendering_params.get_rotation()));
    // and similarly for pitch and roll.

    // Estimate the shape coefficients by fitting the shape to the landmarks:
    Mat affine_from_ortho = fitting::get_3x4_affine_camera_matrix(rendering_params, image.cols, image.rows);
    vector<float> fitted_coeffs = fitting::fit_shape_to_landmarks_linear(morphable_model, affine_from_ortho, image_points, vertex_indices);

    // Obtain the full mesh with the estimated coefficients:
    core::Mesh mesh = morphable_model.draw_sample(fitted_coeffs, vector<float>());

    // Extract the texture from the image using given mesh and camera parameters:
    Mat isomap = render::extract_texture(mesh, affine_from_ortho, image);

    // Save the mesh as textured obj:
    outputfile += fs::path(".obj");
    core::write_textured_obj(mesh, outputfile.string());

    // And save the isomap:
    outputfile.replace_extension(".isomap.png");
    cv::imwrite(outputfile.string(), isomap);

    cout << "Finished fitting and wrote result mesh and isomap to files with basename " << outputfile.stem().stem() << "." << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might because you run it directly without generating it as a project. Check eos documentation:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/patrikhuber/eos.git
mkdir build && cd build # creates a build directory next to the 'eos' folder
cmake -G "<your favourite generator>" ../eos -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../install/
make && make install # or open the project file and build in an IDE like Visual Studio
```

Or it might due to files haven't loaded successfully after your git clone

Hope it helps!